# Flashed bootloader successfully but device doesn't show up in device manager

Tags: bootloader, cortex-m, atmel

I've successfully compiled and flashed the arduino samd bootloader onto a custom atsamd21 board. I am using an external crystal oscillator (32khz) so I am not using the -DCRYSTALLESS option.

Now that I plug it in I don't hear or see anything pop up. Even in the arduino ide it doesn't show up.

What could be the cause(s)?